# Can you access the owning object from a method attribute?

Tags: c#

I am trying to do something like:

```
public class CreateViewModel
{
    ErrorDescriber _describer;
    public CreateViewModel(ErrorDescriber describer)
    {
        _describer = describer;
    }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = _describer.InvalidTitle())]
    [MaxLength(300)]
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

The Required attribute is not aware of any _describer field in the object. Any hint?

Comment: Could `_describer.InvalidTitle()` be different at runtime?  In not can you just make it a const property of `ErrorDescriber`?

Comment: Maybe you can look into [localized validation](http://www.softwareisinthedetails.com/2012/02/aspnet-mvc-validation-attributes.html) for inspiration. The indent is similar, however you will still have to rethink on your design.

Comment: I use an ErrorDescriber class in a similar way to asp.net Identity. Some error messages take a parameter. I just found out I could just make the method static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use instance member for attribute initialization. Only `const` or `static` member can be used.